# Synchronizing two joined table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following requirements:

1. Table Client has two columns ClientID(Int) and Email ID(Varchar 100). ClientID is an identity column with Auto increment value of 1.
2. Table Indicator has two columns ClientID(Int) and Paid(Char 1)

Both the table are joined with the Key clientID.

I am using MS SQL 2008 database. Can you pleases let me know how it is possible to update Indicator table automatically with clientID as soon as new record is created in Client.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You can do it by using trigger.

Comment: Can you please provide a pseudo code to address this?

Comment: Or just using last inserted id? Are you using ORM or plain SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using trigger or you can denormalize your data structure (if you have only `Paid` in `Indicator`, I think the `Paid` is simple property of `Client`) and move it to `Client`.

You can use trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TrigerName
ON Client AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE I
    SET Paid = <your value>
    FROM Indicator I
       JOIN inserted ins
           ON I.ClientID = ins.ClientId
END
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the prompt response.